# Solving a non-linear differential equation of second degree

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

How do I solve the differential equation $y^2= 2px+ p^2 $, $\ $ $p$ $\ $ being $\frac{dy}{dx}$? I came up with this equation accidentally while trying to copy an exercise from the book. The actual problem is fine, but this equation is troubling me for a while. I tried reducing it to Clairaut's form to no avail. I tried solving for $y$ or $x$, but failed. Kindly help me out.

Comment: You can solve for $p$ as $$p = \dfrac{dy}{dx} = -x~\pm~ \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$ However, I am not sure you can solve the resulting differential equation.

Comment: I am totally lost from here. No idea. In fact, I tried fiddling around this format before.

Comment: You would to resort to numerical methods at this point.

Comment: @Isham: Oops - just a typo - corrected - thanks.

Comment: @Isham It should be a $-$

Comment: Hard to believe that this nice looking equation cannot have an elegant solution :(

Comment: I notice that if you take the derivative of $xp^2$ you get $2xpp'+p^2$ which is almost your right side.

Comment: *Almost, this is where the trouble is.